# Overlay image to show like panorama

Tags: html, css

I am looking how to overlay any Image in CSS to show as Panorama. I cannot find the right logic to build it. Maybe by hiding the Heights but this way did not help me.

Solved.. One more Idea brought me to clear my Problem.. Anyway if somebody needs it here is the Solution

```
<div style="position: relative; height:100px; overflow:hidden">
    <img src="photo.jpg" style="margin-top:-50px;" />
</div>
```

Just set the height of DIV Tag and correct the image position with margin-top.

If anybody has another way please share. Thanks

Thanks for others who replied me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should improve your question in my honest opinion.

Comment: A little unclear what you are after. Can you expand or show examples that are similar?

Comment: Please don't post answers inside your question, you can answer your own questions instead if you think they are useful to the community. Delete the question otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for any size of image would be the following CSS:

```
div{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-bottom: calc(100%*9/16);
    position: relative;
}

div img {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can see an example in http://jsfiddle.net/poselab/9vWU8/4/